# How do I read the cell contents using apache poi for xlsx type of excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

It seems I'm in a bit of a pickle, I read various topics about read xls files with hssf but I can't seem to find good xssf tutorials and it's really hard since they have different statements. My code is supposed to read the row 2, column 2 but I get a "getContents() is undefined for the type XSSFComment" error

My code goes something like:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; 

public class parsing{ 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/test.xlsx"); 
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead); 
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
System.out.println(sh.getCellComment(1,1).getContents()); 
} 
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getContents() is undefined for the type XSSFComment
    at parsing.main(parsing.java:18)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Which Apache POI version are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of latest Apache POI the class `XSSFComment` doesn't have `getContents()` method at all.

Instead try to use `getString()` method to get the Comment content. Check the documentation of [Apache POI XSSFComment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFComment.html)

Also check [Apache PoI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellComments) for the Cell Comment example provided.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've used the "cell.getStringCellValue();" and it worked like a charm, the reason I needed to do this individually  was because I need those 10 cells' value to store as a variable since I'll store it in a database. I got one last question though if you wouldn't mind, would it be possible to choose specific cells to store into a variable while on a loop to read the entire spreadsheet?

Comment: You can iterate through cells in whole spread sheet and store its value in may be StringBuffer which can eventually be stored in database. Its upto your requirement which specific cells you need to read that something would be your application logic.

Can you please let me know in detail by example what are you trying to achieve, that will help.

Comment: Let's say there's a sheet with 20 rows and 20 columns, each cell has a value, if I need to read about 30 cells (which could be anywhere on the 20x20 spreadsheet) then my code would be continuously using the get contents but if I would use a loop, I could minimize my 60 lines of code (30 lines for get content, 30 lines to store in a variable). But should I do it? should I loop and read all cells along with the ones I don't need just to shorten my code? is it worth it? or should I just specify the cells I need so I don't have to read every cell including the ones I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getContents() method, use getString()

Comment: Thank you, I used the cell.getStringCellValue();