# Alternate to deprecated .getCell in Apache POI to get the Contents of the row at that column

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/srivaans/Desktop/Trytoread.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int totalnoofrows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int totalnoofcell = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

        System.out.println("No. of rows: " +totalnoofrows);
            System.out.println("No. of cells= " +totalnoofcell);
        for (int row = 0; row<totalnoofrows; row++){
            for( int cell =0;cell<totalnoofcell; cell++){
                System.out.print(sheet.getCell(cell, row).getContents() + "\t");
            }

        }
```

Here is my code. I have to get the data of the row for the following column. .getCell() method has been only for .xls(HSSF) type of file and not for .xlsx(XSSF) type of file.

Can someone please help me for the same.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    sheet.getRow(int rownum).getCell(int cellnum).getXXX();
```

where XXX is whatever you need. it's all in the java docs. there's getStringCellValue(), getBooleanCellValue(), style stuffs, formula stuffs.

also. you should probably do a google & especially search stack overflow. this is related:

[How do I read the cell contents using apache poi for xlsx type of excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467555/how-do-i-read-the-cell-contents-using-apache-poi-for-xlsx-type-of-excel-file?rq=1)